# Can not SSH into ubuntu using external after upgrade to 19.10?

Tags: upgrade, ssh

I can ssh into the machine over the LAN no problem but external no longer works. `ssh -vvv` just says network is unreachable after a long hang.

I think some config must have got wiped. I don't remember what that was yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be merely a change of LAN ip and some port forwardings on the router. Too much state involved here.